# Hound code search engine - index windows local folder

Tags: go, search, hound

My goal is to search code snippets into a huge folder on my win 11 local system.
According documentation, I should be use `vcs : local` to index local folder.

```
"repos" : {
        "DockerTest" : {
            "url" : "https://github.com/my-user/docker-test.git"
        },
        "QuickStart" : {
            "url" : "https://github.com/my-user/start.git"
        },
    "LocalRepo" : {
            "url" : "file:///d/Weblabs/nodejs",
            "vcs" : "local"
            "url-pattern" : {
                "base-url" : "{url}/{path}"
            },
            "vcs-config" : {
                "watch-changes" : true,
                "ignored-files" : []
            }
        }
    }
```

But it go on error

````
symlink Monorepo /data/data/vcs-95d90285ecfae3aca71e8884dcdd8f9398869ea6: file exists```

I have tried also to remove data folder, the git repositories are indexed, not the local folder.


Any suggestion please ?
````